# Multi - Step Approval Process

Tags: approval-process

I have a requirement which I am stating below:

1) when Amount < 100 - Automatically approve the record.

2) When Amount > 100 - Following is conditions:

- a) Notify to member called PD
- if PD approves notify to a member called CFO
- if CFO approves, notify a member called PT.

3)  When Amount > 100 & member PD denies it notify CFO - CFO member denies it again notify to PD again if PD approves notify CFO & now if CFO disapproves go back to PD.

Note : Whoever is notified of the approval or rejection is equivalent to becoming the Approver.

I have achieved 1 and 2 successfully but for 3 i am unable to achieve.

The entry criteria for the Approval Process is When Amount != null

[image]

Answer (score 1):

1 and 2 are straightforward, using the normal functionality in a single approval process.

Option 3 is very tricky, and is not possible with a single approval process.  Upon rejection, you could update a "status" field to indicate rejected, and then use process builder to auto submit to a different approval process to handle each part of the scenario.  I'm still not sure you could get it exactly as described but it may well be possible.

In approvals, on rejection you only have the option of going back one step, or doing a full rejection. And It's not possible to skip a step on the way "up" and hit it on a reject, I have tried that.  So basically you need to do a full reject and then auto submit to a new approval process to route it appropriately.